# What's a metaphor/expression for "confirmation"?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, metaphors

Example:

> I already knew about what she said. Her words were merely a [...].

I checked [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/confirmation) but none of the synonyms seem like a metaphor/expression. Maybe *go ahead*?

Comment: How do you feel about "*just a **formality***"?

Comment: Using 'merely' makes it sound like ['rubber stamp'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rubber%20stamp) would do.

Comment: '.. an endorsement', but I'd use 'merely confirmed my opinion'.

Comment: A _go ahead_ means that you can continue to do something as planned. A _confirmation_ as in your example sentence means that you are told what you already (thought you) knew. These are two different things. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: @oerkelens I don't know. I think both works.

Comment: I saw the weather report this morning. Later my friend tells met it will rain. I knew that already from watching the weather report. vs I'm working on a project, and I need approval from my superior to start on the next phase. He gives me the approval to start the next phase. My friend _confirmed_ something, but my superior gave me a _go ahead_. I cannot see how those two situations are similar, which is why I asked which situation you meant. They are totally different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"an acknowledgement" or "an affirmation"

I already knew about what she said. Her words were merely an acknowledgement.

Comment: While these words are synonyms, they're not metaphors (as specified in the question).

Comment: Asking for metaphors would be off-topic in any case.  Idioms and expressions would be on-topic.

Comment: @Tim Romano - the "Metaphors" tag currently indicates 7 asked this month, 59 this year.

Answer (score 2):

**What's a metaphor/expression for “confirmation”?**

American car-culture has created the idiom **give somebody/something the green light** (as opposed to a red light) based on our experience of waiting in our automobiles at traffic lights.

**green light**:

To give permission for something to happen; "She's waiting for her doctor to give her ***the green light*** to play in Saturday's game."

*Usage notes*: also used in the form give a green light: "The House of Representatives ***gave a green light*** to oil exploration off the East Coast."

The Free Dictionary [green light](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+the+green+light)

Comment: It's similar to giving someone a *go ahead*?

Comment: exactly, jano ...

Comment: Not that this would usually be confused with green light meaning "the go-ahead", but being "green lit" also means there's a hit out on you by a gang or the mob. :-)

Comment: Really? @Kristina Lopez - thanks for the tip. That's a new meaning for me.

Comment: A _go ahead_ means that you can continue to do something as planned. A _confirmation_ as in your example sentence means that you are told what you already (thought you) knew. These are two different things. _The green light_ means "yes, do it" not "yes, your assumption is correct".

Comment: @oerkelens - yes, of course, I was doing my best to satisfy a less than optimal OP construction. For example, **IF** I already knew about what she **said**, THEN Her words were ... REDUNDANT, rather than a confirmation.  Taking into account that janoChen is learning the language (and doing a helluva good job), my guess was that OP was requesting a metaphor or fixed phrase for a "formal affirmation", hence "greenlight".

Answer (score 1):

If you want a metaphor, perhaps *[icing on the cake](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/the-icing-or-frosting-on-the-cake)*

> An attractive but inessential addition or enhancement

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 0):

We can say that her words *corroborated* what you already knew. They were a *corroboration*.